# Rails paperclip-dropbox not uploading to Dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, dropbox

I'm having some issues with the **paperclip-dropbox gem**.

I have a simple User model, with name, password, etc. and an image. I'm trying to upload that image to dropbox, but it's not working.

The file gets saved in my **/system/users/images/000/000/** folder. The **image_file_name**, **image_content_type**, **image_file_size** and **image_updated_at** data is getting saved correctly in my database, along with the user's name, password, etc.

I'm using **ruby 2.2.1p85** and **Rails 4.2.0**. I have the paperclip-dropbox gem in my Gemfile and correctly installed. I have created the app in Dropbox, but in the applications folder nothing gets uploaded.

It would seem like the paperclip-dropbox gem is not doing its job because I can put anything I want in my config/dropbox.yml (I mean, wrong app_key and/or access_token values, for example) and it doesn't throw any authentication error or anything.

Here's some code so you can see what I'm doing and maybe point out what's wrong:

**The User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"],
  :storage => :dropbox,
    :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
    :dropbox_options => {:path => proc { |style| "files/#{id}/#{file.original_filename}" } }

end
```

**Create method on Users Controller:**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I have the **config/dropbox.yml** all set.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your dropbox options should be on the `has_attached_file` method:

```
has_attached_file :image,
    :storage => :dropbox,
    :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
    :dropbox_options => {:path => proc { |style| "files/#{id}/#{file.original_filename}" } }

validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

Comment: I feel pretty dumb right now. It works great, @Lazarus Lazaridis! Thanks a lot for your help!